# DEVELOPER_ERROR with Facebook login on Android whenever creating a new beta build

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, google-play-console

It’s a React Native app, using Firebase auth.

Whenever we create a new build and use fastlane to push this build to the beta track, we get a bunch of DEVELOPER_ERRORs appearing in Sentry.

I would guess that this is something to do with the Play Store review process, but the Sentry logs don’t contain any useful information and Facebook login otherwise functions perfectly in production using the same app binary, and I don’t know where to start in terms of reproducing this in a dev environment.

Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed? Either to get this fixed or get extra debugging.

Theory 1, invalid key hash.
I’ve made sure that they key hashes are added to the Facebook developers site, both from our upload key, the key in App Signing in the Play Console, and the keys in Firebase Distribute.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your SHA1 key to firebase console configuration.
Firebase console ( https://console.firebase.google.com ) -> your project -> configuration -> scroll to

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTVOn.png)

Comment: Thanks for making a SO account to answer this question! It looks like were missing a key hash there for the app upload key. It now has 3 pairs of hashes there, a sha1+sha256 for each of
* Our app upload key
* The certificate in Firebase App Distribution 
* The App signing key certificate under App Integrity in the Play Console
We'll see if the extra key hash changes things. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sadly this hasn't fixed the issue